# What is the fastest way to find an edge between two given vertexes in orientDB

Tags: orientdb, query-performance, orient-sql

I currently have 2 vertex collections named `community` and `user`.
Each user whom is member of a community is linked to that community using the edge `community_user`.

I am trying to update a `community_user` edge for a given user their _id and a given `community` its _id.

```
SELECT read from community_user where 
     outV() in (select @rid FROM `community` WHERE ( `_id` = '5ab283c35b6b9435d4c9a958' )) 
     and 
     inV() in (select @rid from user where _id  = 'x5mxEBwhMfiLSQHaK')
```

This query does work, although it is rather slow once the `community_user` edge is getting filled.

Is there a way to index this search or faster solution to find the value I need?

My current relevant indexes are on `community._id` and `user._id`

The `EXPLAIN` of that query results in:

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "@type": "d",
            "@version": 0,
            "documentReads": 1,
            "fullySortedByIndex": false,
            "documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass": 1,
            "recordReads": 1,
            "fetchingFromTargetElapsed": 0,
            "indexIsUsedInOrderBy": false,
            "currentMatch": null,
            "compositeIndexUsed": 1,
            "current": "#169:839",
            "depth": 0,
            "involvedIndexes": [
                "user._id"
            ],
            "limit": -1,
            "matched": {
                "$ORIENT_DEFAULT_ALIAS_0": "#1770:0",
                "theEdge": "#1817:1889"
            },
            "evaluated": 1,
            "elapsed": 1490.7661,
            "resultType": "collection",
            "resultSize": 1,
            "@fieldTypes": "documentReads=l,documentAnalyzedCompatibleClass=l,recordReads=l,fetchingFromTargetElapsed=l,compositeIndexUsed=l,current=x,involvedIndexes=e,evaluated=l,elapsed=f"
        }
    ],
    "notification": "Query executed in 1.521 sec. Returned 1 record(s)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using a MATCH statement

```
MATCH
  {class:community, where:(_id = '5ab283c35b6b9435d4c9a958' )}
    .outE(){as:theEdge}.inV(){class:user, where:(_id  = 'x5mxEBwhMfiLSQHaK')}
RETURN $elements
```

Comment: I tried this query and it is even slower then the one I had.
Mine executed in +-600ms and yours takes up about 1.5 seconds.

I'll add an explain of the query if that might help you.

Comment: Yours does indeed limit the records which are read to 1 although the speed is still horrible.